# Expand index notation equation using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Below I have an equation written using index notation. This equation can be expressed with the six equations on the figure.

[image: Equation using index notation]

The first equation is expanded using index notation (einstein notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). 
In U_k,k the comma is a convention for derivative. Since we have repeated indices (k,k) we apply the summation convention and get (du_1/dx_1 + du_2/dx_2 + du_3/dx_3). On the figure the terms u_1, u_2 and u_3 are written as u, v and w and they are differentiated by x_1, x_2 and x_3 (x, y, and z).

I am new to python and Sympy and I saw that there is a tensor module but I could not see if there is something already implemented in Sympy where I can write the first equation (with index) and from that obtain the other six relations.

Comment: The six equations involve  v, w, tau which do not appear in the first; how do you suppose SymPy could come up with them?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear... I edit the question to provide more information. Let me know if there is something that it is still not clear. Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone offer a better solution to this question? Answer 2 below gets the following error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MutableDenseMatrix' and 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there is no straightforward way to do what you ask.

I shall suggest a trick that should work, by using *IndexedBase* (that is, symbols indexed by other symbols), followed by a replacement.

Declare your symbols:

```
U = IndexedBase("U")
l = symbols("lambda")
var("mu u v w x y z i j k")
```

Declare your expressions (no Einstein summation, so explicitly put a *Sum*):

```
sij = l*Sum(U[k, k], (k, 0, 2)) * KroneckerDelta(i, j) + mu*(U[i, j] + U[j, i])
```

Define a replacement function: will match *U[0, 0]* to *Derivative(u, x)* and so on according to the index:

```
def replace_U(uij):
    i1, i2 = uij.indices
    return Derivative([u, v, w][i1], [x, y, z][i2])
```

Now, run over all *i*, *j* indices replacing *U[i, j]* with integer values first, then replacing expressions like *U[0, 0]*, ...

```
for ii in range(3):
    for ji in range(3):
        if ii < ji:
            continue
        pprint(sij.doit().xreplace({i: ii, j: ji}).replace(lambda v: v.base == U, replace_U))
```

Remember: *Sum.doit()* expands the summation. Condition *ii >= ji* is used to avoid printing the same expressions twice (your equation is symmetric in *i, j*).

Note that *U[i, j]* in the code above is just a symbol, *i* and *j* have no special meaning except as indices to *U*. The replacement function assigns derivatives to them.

The output I get is:

```
  ⎛d       d       d    ⎞       d    
λ⋅⎜──(u) + ──(v) + ──(w)⎟ + 2⋅μ⋅──(u)
  ⎝dx      dy      dz   ⎠       dx   
  ⎛d       d    ⎞
μ⋅⎜──(u) + ──(v)⎟
  ⎝dy      dx   ⎠
  ⎛d       d       d    ⎞       d    
λ⋅⎜──(u) + ──(v) + ──(w)⎟ + 2⋅μ⋅──(v)
  ⎝dx      dy      dz   ⎠       dy   
  ⎛d       d    ⎞
μ⋅⎜──(u) + ──(w)⎟
  ⎝dz      dx   ⎠
  ⎛d       d    ⎞
μ⋅⎜──(v) + ──(w)⎟
  ⎝dz      dy   ⎠
  ⎛d       d       d    ⎞       d    
λ⋅⎜──(u) + ──(v) + ──(w)⎟ + 2⋅μ⋅──(w)
  ⎝dx      dy      dz   ⎠       dz
```

> I am new to python and Sympy and I saw that there is a tensor module
>   but I could not see if there is something already implemented in Sympy
>   where I can write the first equation (with index) and from that obtain
>   the other six relations.

There is *sympy.tensor.tensor*, which supports abstract index notation (a restricted kind of Einstein summation). Unfortunately, it does not support derivatives.

If you want to work on components, there's a recent addition: [sympy.tensor.array](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html). It provides multidimensional arrays, tensor products and contractions, and derivatives by arrays.

Answer (score 2):

As [Francesco Bonazzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5190654/francesco-bonazzi) stated, there is another way to implement equations using [sympy.tensor.array](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html). This method has the advantage of being easy to implement derivatives.

The sample code (for jupyter) is as follows:

```
from sympy import *
lam, mu, x, y, z = symbols("lambda mu x y z")
u, v, w = symbols("u v w", cls=Function)
du = derive_by_array([u(x, y, z), v(x, y, z), w(x, y, z)], [x, y, z])
sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * Array(eye(3)) + mu * (du + transpose(du))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(i, 3):
        display(Eq(Symbol("sigma_{}{}".format(i+1, j+1)), sig[i, j]))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: It looks there is an error when I'm trying to run this code as follows: 
line 5, in <module>
    sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * eye(3) + mu * (du + transpose(du))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MutableDenseMatrix' and 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray'

Comment: Hi, @Mohammad . If you get that error, you can fix it as follows.
`sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * Array(eye(3)) + mu * (du + transpose(du))`

Comment: Thank you, @Mohammad . I've fixed it to display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to this question. The code displays/prints results and does not give an error due to its computation per index notation.

Comments are welcome for further (i) optimization and printing results suitable for scientific publications. It is currently looks awkward.

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative
from sympy import * 
lam, mu, x, y, z = symbols("lambda mu x y z")
u, v, w = symbols("u v w", cls=Function)
du = derive_by_array([u(x, y, z), v(x, y, z), w(x, y, z)], [x, y, z])
sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1))*Array(eye(3))  + mu * (du + transpose(du))
alist = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(i, 3):
        alist.append(Eq(Symbol("sigma_{}{}".format(i+1, j+1)), sig[i, j]))
        init_printing()
```

[image]