# Einstein summation convention in sympy

Tags: sympy

I would like to expand the following expression in `sympy`. This expression uses Einstein summation convention:

[image]

I have found [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647370/expand-index-notation-equation-using-sympy) addressing a similar situation. Also [the docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/indexed.html) provide some information, but it is too abstract to put into use.

How can I expand the expression using `sympy` while respecting the rules for summation convention? Thanks.

Comment: There is a module sympy.tensor.tensor that supports implicit summation convention, unfortunately it does not support derivatives. I fear that you need to use the Sum to express your quantity.