# Index notation and sympy: How do we use sympy package effectively for equations are written using index notation in python?

Tags: python, sympy

Here is my experience to learn how to use python for a mathematical formulations using index notation and obstacles. A record can be found here at [Expand index notation equation using sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647370/expand-index-notation-equation-using-sympy)

```
from sympy import simplify, tensorcontraction, tensorproduct
from sympy import *
lam, mu, x, y, z = symbols("lambda mu x y z")
u, v, w = symbols("u v w", cls=Function)
du = derive_by_array([u(x, y, z), v(x, y, z), w(x, y, z)], [x, y, z])
sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * eye(3) + mu * (du + transpose(du))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(i, 3):
        Eq(Symbol("sigma_{}{}".format(i+1, j+1)), sig[i, j])
```

The error is TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MutableDenseMatrix' and 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray'

Thank You for Your Attention!

Comment: To me at least, it is not entirely clear what you are asking. Perhaps you could try to clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: where's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to see actual `sympy` variables, and the traceback - or at least a clear statement of where the error occurred.  I'll show what I expect.

Running your code piece by piece in a `isympy` session.

```
In [1]: lam, mu, x, y, z = symbols("lambda mu x y z")
   ...: u, v, w = symbols("u v w", cls=Function)
   ...: du = derive_by_array([u(x, y, z), v(x, y, z), w(x, y, z)], [x, y, z])

In [2]: du
Out[2]: 
⎡∂               ∂               ∂             ⎤
⎢──(u(x, y, z))  ──(v(x, y, z))  ──(w(x, y, z))⎥
⎢∂x              ∂x              ∂x            ⎥
⎢                                              ⎥
⎢∂               ∂               ∂             ⎥
⎢──(u(x, y, z))  ──(v(x, y, z))  ──(w(x, y, z))⎥
⎢∂y              ∂y              ∂y            ⎥
⎢                                              ⎥
⎢∂               ∂               ∂             ⎥
⎢──(u(x, y, z))  ──(v(x, y, z))  ──(w(x, y, z))⎥
⎣∂z              ∂z              ∂z            ⎦

In [3]: sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * eye(3) + mu * (du + transpos
   ...: e(du))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-181d779e2c85> in <module>
----> 1 sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * eye(3) + mu * (du + transpose(du))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MutableDenseMatrix' and 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray'
```

OK, that occurs in a long expression, but I see only one `+`.  What are the terms?

```
In [4]: type(du)
Out[4]: sympy.tensor.array.dense_ndim_array.ImmutableDenseNDimArray
```

`transpose(du)` is also that, and `du+transpose(du)` runs.

But there's another plus - with `eye(3)`:

```
In [12]: type(eye(3))
Out[12]: sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix
```

So `eye(3)` is the wrong type to add to the `du` expression.

What does the docs say about these Matrix types and their compatibility?

---

Change the type of the `eye` matrix, and the addition works:

```
In [19]: E3 = ImmutableDenseNDimArray(eye(3))
In [20]: E3+du;
In [22]: sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1)) * E3 + mu * (du + transpose(du))
```

`sig` is a matrix:

```
In [25]: type(sig)
Out[25]: sympy.tensor.array.dense_ndim_array.ImmutableDenseNDimArray
```

Your loop  works, but doesn't save or display anything.  We can collect values in a list (or matrix):

```
In [26]: alist = []
    ...: for i in range(3):
    ...:     for j in range(i, 3):
    ...:         alist.append(Eq(Symbol("sigma_{}{}".format(i+1, j+1)), sig[i, j
    ...: ]))
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [27]: alist
Out[27]: 
⎡        ⎛∂                ∂                ∂             ⎞       ∂           
⎢σ₁₁ = λ⋅⎜──(u(x, y, z)) + ──(v(x, y, z)) + ──(w(x, y, z))⎟ + 2⋅μ⋅──(u(x, y, z
⎣        ⎝∂x               ∂y               ∂z            ⎠       ∂x          

            ⎛∂                ∂             ⎞          ⎛∂                ∂    
)), σ₁₂ = μ⋅⎜──(u(x, y, z)) + ──(v(x, y, z))⎟, σ₁₃ = μ⋅⎜──(u(x, y, z)) + ──(w(
            ⎝∂y               ∂x            ⎠          ⎝∂z               ∂x   

 ...
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer. When I push RUN in python it does not create a matrix for me and the error (in problem statement) appears.

Comment: I wasn't trying give you a matrix (with that `Eq` part).  I was trying solve the `sig` line error `In[22]`

Comment: I guess I understand now your answer much better. Indeed you fixed sig line error. Furthermore, one can suggest that sig = lam * tensorcontraction(du, (0, 1))*Array(eye(3))  + mu * (du + transpose(du)) . Right?